# Find basis of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the vector space of positive real numbers over field of real numbers and addition of vectors $v$,$u$ as the following,
$u+v = uv$ , scalar multiplication as the following, $\lambda u = u^\lambda $

What is an example of a basis of the vector space? How do we form such basis?

Answer (score 0):

This vector space is $1$-dimensional. Take $v = e$, then for every $u \in \left]0,\rightarrow\right]$, there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ with $u = \lambda^v$.

You can gain some intuition of this vector space by considering logarithms: If $u,v \in V$, then $\log u + \log v = \log (u + v)$, where the latter sum is vector sum. If $\lambda$ is a scalar, $\log (\lambda v) = \lambda \log v$.